# Connection from server to client in rdp session

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

My "client PC" is connected to server via RDP. I want to send a message from server to WCF service, that is hosted on client PC. Is it possible (can server send anything to client PC)?

Comment: What you want may be simpler than trying to use WCF, try the msg command: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg

Comment: Msg command only able me to send a message to client logged in rdp session, but i want to send a "message" to his PC. My scenario is:
1. Log in to RDP
2. Open application in RDP Session
3. Application sends a message to WCF service, which is hosted on CLIENT PC.

Comment: It sounds like you need a WCF client application on the RDP server that monitors RDP sockets and when a new one is created will use the WCF framework to initiate a new connection to the newly connected client and send data. As long as the client has the service active and is able to accept connections, it would be a server in its own right and so I don't see how it wouldn't be possible - but it would require knowledge of how to build that sort of thing in WCF (and that would be a better question for StackOverflow).